# How do I add a transformed variable to a Dataframe with other variables in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I'm new to pandas and sometimes things can be confusing to me. so I have a column in a Dataframe(df) column name is 'Black or African American' that I converted from string percent to float but now I want to add the converted variable back to a Dataframe or create a new Dataframe that has those variables from before.how do I go about that? please help out this is error message ':1: SettingWithCopyWarning:

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead'

```
black = race_df['Black or African American'].str.rstrip('%').astype(float) / 100
black.head(5)   


0    0.264
1    0.031
2    0.041
3    0.153
4    0.055
Name: Black or African American, dtype: float64

race_df['Black or African American'] = race_df['Black or African  American'].str.rstrip('%').astype(float) / 100
```

I've tried the above code and I'm still getting errors

Comment: Have you tried this? `race_df['Black or African American Float'] = race_df['Black or African American'].str.rstrip('%').astype(float) / 100`

Comment: okay that worked but I'm still got an error message

Comment: So add your error message to the question ;)